# How to install gnome-schedule for 16.10

Tags: gnome, cron, gnome-schedule

I recently upgraded to 16.10 and found most things that worked in 15.10 are working in 16.10 - - with one notable exception: `gnome-schedule`.

Many of the suite of gnome utilities are in 16.10 but not gnome-schedule.

Downloaded the source code for gnome-schedule v 2.3 and it says it needs `autoconf` v 1.7 - - 16.10 says that v 1.5 is the latest.  errrrr!

Any chance we can get gnome-schedule added to Ubuntu repositories anything soon?

Comment: Found a Debian release of gnome-schedule_2.1.1-4_all.deb but it would not install on 16.10

Comment: try to install dependancies using `sudo apt install python-gtk2-dev python-gconf at gnome-doc-utils scrollkeeper`.

Comment: gnome-schedule has been deprecated. Here the the August 2017 solution for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/942401/how-to-control-cron-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 1):

gnome-schedule was [removed](https://bugs.debian.org/808060) from Debian and Ubuntu because it's very old and hasn't been updated in years. The last supported version of Ubuntu to still have it available in the repositories is 14.04 LTS.

Ubuntu 15.10 is no longer [supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Comment: Is there an alternative other than command line?  CLI:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto